# Which one is better ?SQL server 2012 or Oracle 11g

Tags: sql-server, spatial-database, oracle-spatial

I want to learn a database server, SQL server 2012 or Oracle 11g . I surf in the internet to compare SQL server and Oracle for spatial data and found good websites such as  [gisboston](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=sqlserver2008r2_oracle11gr2_postgis15_compare).it was very interesting for me but i want to compare oracle and sql server about job opportunity in GIS. which one is better to find a good job?
 which one is better to manage spatial data ?

Comment: What spatial functions are you going to do? postgis maybe a contender too.

Comment: post GIS supports more functions than SQL server and Oracle (see GISboston website), but question is about SQL server and Oracle comparation for GIS Job opportunity not functions.

Comment: The best to find a good job is you.

Comment: Thanks Fardosht Amirpanahi. I do appreciate your help. Your answer helps me clearing my mind quite a lot. I have started learning SQL server 2008. I hope that within couple of days I'll be able to work on the same. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have administered SDE and designed enterprise GIS in both Oracle and SQL Server.  17 years ago when I got my Oracle Master Certificate, I used to consider SQL Server nothing more than a beefed up Access database. Things have changed.

There are new capabilities in SQL Server which have had such a fundamental impact on geodatabase management that has forced even Esri to adopt SQL Server for its standards.   Oracle spatial was released with Oracle 7.  Since then, no one else, neither Esri, MapInfo, SmallWorld, Autodesk nor Google has adopted Oracle spatial. SQL Server was released April 2012.

Let me recommend you to take a look at this review: [sql-server-vs-oracle-bdms-comparison](http://www.slideshare.net/SoftexSoftware/sql-server-vs-oracle-dbms-comparison-24215631).

Comment: "Since then, no one else, neither Esri, MapInfo, SmallWorld, Autodesk nor Google has adopted Oracle spatial" Can you clarify what you mean by "has adobted Oracle Spatial"? The MapInfo products from Pitney Bowes Software still support Oracle Spatial just as they support SQL Server (Spatial).